# how to take the product of all the cells in a cell array in matlab

Tags: matlab

how can I take the product of all the cells of a cell array in Matlab? In my case, I have a cell array `try_this` with 125 cells. Each cell is a 3x3 matrix.

I would like to take the product over all of these matrices.

Is there a good way to do this?

Comment: Take a look at [`cellfun`](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html). Also, do you mean regular matrix product or element-wise product?

Comment: regular matrix product. When I do cellfun as `cellfun(prod,try_this)` I get an error. It says Not enough input arguments.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Sorry, I just realised that `cellfun` won't work here as I thought since you are not applying the function to each cell individually, but rather sequentially for each earlier multiplication result and the next cell element.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to do this using a `for`-loop. The following collects the output piece-by-piece to the array `result`:

```
result = try_this{1}*try_this{2}; %// multiply first two cells
for k = 3:numel(try_this)
    result = result * try_this{k}; %// C{1}*C{2}* ... * C{k}
end
```

Edit: As discussed in the comments below, vectorizing such repeated matrix multiplication is not straightforward.

Comment: Yeah that's what I did but I'm trying to figure out how to vectorize it because there are a lot of matrices.

Comment: @Glassjawed okay. I'll leave this answer as a reference, let's see if someone swoops in with a cool vectorized solution ;)

Comment: @Glassjawed Matrix multiplication like that can't be easily vectorized. Write out on paper the case for 3-4-5 matrix products, how the indices are intertwined... Even if one (and I mean Divakar) could vectorize it somehow, it would probably have huge memory overhead. In other words: for a matrix product of 125 matrices, you need a 124-uple sum...

Comment: Switching to a 3x3x125 matrix instead of cell arrays and apply this solution is what I expect to be the fastest possibility.

Comment: @Glassjawed And for Daniel's suggestion: use `cat(3,try_this{:})` for laziness (and slowness, probably).